# How do I ask for multiple years for example I want 2021-2023 of march

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT
    year,
    month AS month_nm,  
case    
    when upper(month) in ('JAN','FEB','MAR') THEN 'Q1'  
    when upper(month) in ('APR','MAY','JUN') THEN 'Q2'  
    when upper(month) in ('JUL','AUG','SEP') THEN 'Q3'  
    when upper(month) in ('OCT','NOV','DEC') THEN 'Q4'  
END AS quarter, 
scenario,
```

Tried 2021,2022,20223

Comment: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423302/why-does-tagging-multiple-rdbms-products-make-my-question-unclear) I removed the conflicting tags, please tag only the one database you are running.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean in WHERE? Or you want columns... Please attach data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres:

```
select 
   to_char(dt, 'YYYY') AS year, 
   to_char(dt, 'MON') AS month,  
   'Q'||to_char(dt, 'Q') AS quarter
from  
   generate_series('01/01/2021'::date, '03/01/2023'::date, '1 month') as t(dt);
 year    | month   | quarter
---------+---------+----------
 2021    | JAN     | Q1
 2021    | FEB     | Q1
 2021    | MAR     | Q1
 2021    | APR     | Q2
 2021    | MAY     | Q2
 2021    | JUN     | Q2
 2021    | JUL     | Q3
 2021    | AUG     | Q3
 2021    | SEP     | Q3
 2021    | OCT     | Q4
 2021    | NOV     | Q4
 2021    | DEC     | Q4
 2022    | JAN     | Q1
 2022    | FEB     | Q1
 2022    | MAR     | Q1
 2022    | APR     | Q2
 2022    | MAY     | Q2
 2022    | JUN     | Q2
 2022    | JUL     | Q3
 2022    | AUG     | Q3
 2022    | SEP     | Q3
 2022    | OCT     | Q4
 2022    | NOV     | Q4
 2022    | DEC     | Q4
 2023    | JAN     | Q1
 2023    | FEB     | Q1
 2023    | MAR     | Q1
(27 rows)
```

`